# CRM trying re-create 'Business Closure Calendar' calendar every minute

Tags: iis, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, event-log

We are getting following error in event log because `InternalOperationPlugin` is trying to create 'Business Closure Calendar' in Calender entity almost every minute.

`InternalOperationPlugin` is a core system plugin which is registered on Stage 30 (non-customizable). Can anyone give an idea why core plugin is trying to create this record every minute.

We are on Roll up 8 and not in position to install latest.

Thanks in Advance

```
The Web Service plug-in failed in OrganizationId: 07ae1f6f-237f-e111-83c6-005056b41d30; SdkMessageProcessingStepId: 22ccbb1b-ea3e-db11-86a7-000a3a5473e8; 
    EntityName: calendar; 
    Stage: 30; 
    MessageName: RetrieveMultiple; 
    AssemblyName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin, Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; 
ClassName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; 

Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)
    at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
    at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)

Inner Exception: System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '7fdf4980-237f-e111-83c6-005056b41d30'  Key being added: '7fdf4980-237f-e111-83c6-005056b41d30'
    at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
    at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.CalendarService.RetrieveMultiple(EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context)
```

** Error from Event Log **

at VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
at Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
at MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
at InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
at ExternalMessageDispatcher.ExecuteInternal(IInProcessOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory, IPlatformMessageDispatcherFactory dispatcherFactory, String messageName, String requestName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, ParameterCollection fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId, Guid transactionContextId, Int32 invocationSource, Nullable`1 requestId, Version endpointVersion)
at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)
at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)
at InprocessServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)
at SandboxSdkListener.Execute(SandboxCallInfo callInfo, SandboxSdkContext requestContext, String operation, Byte[] serializedRequest)
at
at SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
at ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
at ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
at ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
at AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
at AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(Object state)
at SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
at AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at NegotiateStream.ProcessFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at NegotiateStream.ReadCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(Int32 bytes)
at FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
at AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at ReadAsyncResult.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
at SocketConnection.AsyncReadCallback(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 bytesRead)
at IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at _IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

> Web Service Plug-in failed in SdkMessageProcessingStepId: {22CCBB1B-EA3E-DB11-86A7-000A3A5473E8}; EntityName: calendar; Stage: 30; MessageName: RetrieveMultiple; AssemblyName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin, Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; ClassName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>   Inner Exception: System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '7fdf4980-237f-e111-83c6-005056b41d30'  Key being added: '7fdf4980-237f-e111-83c6-005056b41d30'
>   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.CalendarService.RetrieveMultiple(EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context)
>   .

**UPDATE**

I have already checked Calendar Entity. There is only one record with Id equals to '7fdf4980-237f-e111-83c6-005056b41d30'. Mpreover, I have searched whole database to find out if there is any other record using same Id.

Comment: Do you have any custom plugins? Do you have any custom code that is accessing CRM using the SDK?

Comment: No, we don't have any custom plugin on calendar. InternalOperationPlugin is core CRM plugin.

Comment: It might be a CRM 2011 Rollup 8 issue: community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/119340.aspx.  I would strengthen this assumption by the fact that the version of code I have (Rollup 13) doesn't have any code in that method that performs and insert into a hash table.

Comment: @Daryl that is my Colleague's post :) As I mentioned, we are not in position to install rollups. Regards

Comment: I would grab the Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.dll, and decompile it to see what information it is looking on.  Maybe you could find what it is, and delete it.

Comment: Have you done a search across all the uniqueidentifier columns in the CRM Org Database for __7fdf4980-237f-e111-83c6-005056b41d30__. My guess is you have some DB corruption where this value is used twice.

Specifically, what is happening is that a RetrieveMultiple on the Calendar entity is executing and this is the code that handles such a request. In that process it is, at some point, ending up with two records from SQL that both have the ID of __7fdf4980-237f-e111-83c6-005056b41d30__. I would need to see all instances of that ID in the CRM DB to get any further.

Comment: @Nicknow when I run query on CalendarSet where Id is equal to Guid it returns only one record back which is 'Business Closure Calendar'

Comment: I have also queries all CRM tables in SQL Server to check if Guid is duplicated somewhere. But can't find used anywhere other than Calendar.

Comment: Have you been able to narrow down the steps prior to the error with Verbose tracing?

Comment: @Nicknow problem is only in Live environment, so I am finding it very difficult to narrow down the steps while 800 other users are also accessing at the same time. We need to schedule it outside working hours I think.

Comment: Have you tried taking the database and deploying it to a clean VM? If the problem continues in the clean VM then you could easily trace with no external activity. Also, if you are running multiple front-ends can you isolate one for tracing in the off hours?